# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll Incorrect syntax near 'b'

Tags: c#, sql

i got this error message when i run my code. It said *"An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'b'."* but i dont know how to solve it. Actually i refer someone code and it just the same as their code but still i got error.

this is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace myCookbook
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        string connectionString;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCookbook.Properties.Settings.cookBookDatabaseconnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            InsertResipi();
        }

        private void InsertResipi()
        {
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Recipe", connection))
            {
                DataTable RecipeTable = new DataTable();
                myAdapter.Fill(RecipeTable);
                listRecipes.DisplayMember = "ResepiName";
                listRecipes.ValueMember = "Id";
                listRecipes.DataSource = RecipeTable;
            }
        }

        private void InsertIngredient()
        {
            string myQuery = " SELECT a.IngredientName FROM Ingredient a" +
            "INNER JOIN ResipiIngredient b ON a.Id = b.IngredientId" +
            "WHERE b.ResipiId = @ResipiId";

            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand myCommand  = new SqlCommand(myQuery, connection))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand))
            {
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResipiId", listRecipes.SelectedValue);
                DataTable IngredientTable = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(IngredientTable); // the error message highlight this line
                listIngredient.DisplayMember = "IngredientName";
                listIngredient.ValueMember = "Id";
                listIngredient.DataSource = IngredientTable;
            }
        }

        private void listRecipes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show(listRecipes.SelectedValue.ToString()); //show id
            InsertIngredient();
        }
    }
}
```

this is my references

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace databasecookbook
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string connectiondenganawak;
        SqlConnection connectionhati;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectiondenganawak =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    ["databasecookbook.Properties.Settings.cookbookConnectionString"].
    ConnectionString;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isirecipe();
        }

        void isirecipe()
        {
            using (connectionhati = new SqlConnection(connectiondenganawak))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapterawak = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Recipe", connectionhati))
            {
                DataTable RecipeTable = new DataTable();
                adapterawak.Fill(RecipeTable);
                listBoxRecipe.DisplayMember = "Name";
                listBoxRecipe.ValueMember = "ID";
                listBoxRecipe.DataSource = RecipeTable;
            }
        }

        void isiingredient()
        {
            string querycinta = " SELECT a.Name FROM Ingredient a" +
            "INNER JOIN RecipeIngredient b ON a.Id = b.IngredientID" +
            "WHERE b.RecipeID = @RecipeID";

             using (connectionhati = new SqlConnection(connectiondenganawak))
            using (SqlCommand commandawak =new SqlCommand(querycinta,connectionhati))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapterawak = new SqlDataAdapter(commandawak))
            {
                commandawak.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecipeID", listBoxRecipe.SelectedValue);
                DataTable IngredientTable = new DataTable();
                adapterawak.Fill(IngredientTable);
                listBoxIngredients.DisplayMember = "Name";
                listBoxIngredients.ValueMember = "ID";
                listBoxIngredients.DataSource = IngredientTable;
            }
        }

        private void listBoxRecipe_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isiingredient();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm betting the SQL query is incorrect - what happens when you take the query and run it directly in SQL Server?

Comment: Look in the debugger what `myQuery ` contains: "SELECT a.IngredientName FROM Ingredient aINNER JOIN ResipiIngredient b ON a.Id = b.IngredientIdWHERE b.ResipiId = @ResipiId". You need to add spaces around words.

Comment: @DourHighArch what do you mean by add spaces around words?

Comment: @5c625b7c do you mean copy the query and run it on sql server ? what   i did was copy the query and run it in sql query in c# and i got the error Incorrect syntax near '+'. Sorry, im just a beginner cant understand  what   do you mean by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string that you get lacks whitespace around line breaks: when you concatenate, say, `" SELECT a.Name FROM Ingredient a" + "INNER JOIN RecipeIngredient b ON a.Id = b.IngredientID"`, there is no space between `a` and `INNER JOIN`, so query syntax is incorrect.

C# provides a built-in solution for problem through *verbatim string literals*, i.e. literals starting in `@`. These literals can include line breaks:

```
string myQuery =@"
    SELECT a.IngredientName FROM Ingredient a
    INNER JOIN ResipiIngredient b ON a.Id = b.IngredientId
    WHERE b.ResipiId = @ResipiId
";
```

This query has valid syntax when you pass it to SQL Server, and it also reads nicely on the screen.